# Closure problem with image upload measurement

Tags: javascript, file, upload, closures, onload

To check an uploaded img's original width and height when it's uploaded (and then resize it accordingly), I'm using the following approach:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

//Initiate the JavaScript Image object.
var image = new Image(0,0);

//Read the contents of Image File.
reader.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[0]);
reader.onload = function () {

  //Set the Base64 string return from FileReader as source.
  image.src = this.result;

  //Validate the File Height and Width.
  image.onload = function () {

    var height = this.naturalHeight;
    var width = this.naturalWidth;
    if (height > 100 || width > 100) {

      // Do needed transformation      

    }
    
  };
};
```

Okay, so far so good. But now, when I change this to be an iteration for multiple file uploads, like so:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < fileUpload.files.length; i++ ) {

  var reader = new FileReader();

  //Initiate the JavaScript Image object.
  var image = new Image(0,0);

  var iteratedFile = fileUpload.files[i];

  //Read the contents of Image File.
  reader.readAsDataURL(iteratedFile);
  reader.onload = function () {

    //Set the Base64 string return from FileReader as source.
    image.src = this.result;

    //Validate the File Height and Width.
    image.onload = function () {

      var height = this.naturalHeight;
      var width = this.naturalWidth;
      if (height > 100 || width > 100) {

        // Fails to do anything related to i; i is undefined here, returns undefined too 
        console.log( fileUpload.files[i] );

        // Returns the last iterated name
        console.log( iteratedFile );    

      }
    
    };
  };

}
```

I'm unable to access the iterated file in the inner listener. How come?
When I write `console.log( iteratedFile )` where I've written it, I actually always get the name of the last iterated file, which made me actually notice that this was a closure problem. However, when I write `console.log( i );` or `console.log(fileUpload.files[i])` at the same place instead of that line, I get `undefined`, which I don't really understand. How can I make `i` / the iterated file available in the most inner scope (to access stuff like its name, its mime etc.)?

***UPDATE***

By adding `(i)` to the end of the function definition of the `reader.onload function`; I can now console.log the correct value of i inside the outer function for all three iterations, but then get a `GET` request 404 error sent to the `pages_URL/undefined` displayed in the console. WTH?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoping the lexical environment of `i` to an IIFE called inside the loop actually was enough to make it work like a charm:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < fileUpload.files.length; i++ ) {

  (function(){

    var reader = new FileReader();

    //Initiate the JavaScript Image object.
    var image = new Image(0,0);

    var iteratedFile = fileUpload.files[i];

    //Read the contents of Image File.
    reader.readAsDataURL(iteratedFile);
    reader.onload = function () {

      //Set the Base64 string return from FileReader as source.
      image.src = this.result;

      //Validate the File Height and Width.
      image.onload = function () {

        var height = this.naturalHeight;
        var width = this.naturalWidth;
        if (height > 100 || width > 100) {

          // Works now
          console.log( fileUpload.files[i] );

          // Returns the iterated file
          console.log( iteratedFile );    

        }
    
      };
    };

  }());

}
```